# Excel VBA InStr function

Tags: vba, excel

Why does my InStr function return 0 when it clearly is part of the HTML string?

I cannot post this without more text.I cannot post this without more text.I cannot post this without more text.I cannot post this without more text.I cannot post this without more text.I cannot post this without more text.

```
Sub ImportBPlans()
    Dim BPlan As String, FullHTML As String, URL1 As String, Cut1 As String, T1 As String
    Dim FO As String, LO As String, Other1 As Long

    For i = 2 To LastRow

        T1 = WB1.Cells(i, 1).Value

        URL1 = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q/pr?s=" + T1 + "+Profile"
        FullHTML = GetHTML(URL1)
        BPlan = "&nbsp;</th></tr></table><p>"
        x = Len(FullHTML)
        FO = InStr(FullHTML, BPlan, CompareMethod.Text) + Len(BPlan)
        LO = InStr(FO, FullHTML, "<")
        Cut1 = Left(FullHTML, LO)
        Cut1 = Right(Cut1, FO - LO)
        WB5.Cells(i, 1).Value = Cut1

    Next i


End Sub

Function GetHTML(URL As String) As String
    Dim HTML As String
    Dim htmlBDY As New HTMLDocument
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .Send
        htmlBDY.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        GetHTML = htmlBDY.body.outerHTML
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: You have a couple of `INSTR`. Which one is the problem? Have you tried using the debugger to inspect the variable contents? They mightn't be what you expect.

Comment: Instr returns `integer` and you are taking it in `FO` and `LO` which is a `string`. Please correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    FO = InStr(1, FullHTML, BPlan, vbTextCompare) + Len(BPlan)
```

Comment: So you use this in your next question and don't even accept it here?

Answer (score 0):

FO and LO are defined as `string`.
it should be `integer` as Instr returns `integer`.
Get it corrected.

```
Public Shared Function InStr(_
   ByVal String1 As String, _
   ByVal String2 As String, _
   Optional ByVal Compare As CompareMethod _
) As Integer
```

Comment: While you are 100% correct and while the types should be corrected, this will not fix the problem that the OP is asking about. Whatever numeric value is returned from InStr() will be coerced to a string value as the code currently stands.

Comment: certainly code needs to be corrected as it uses `RIGHT` and `LEFT` function which certainly requires number in its second argument while i can see it passes string FO and LO . i am not sure how it is working him.

Comment: I did the changes that everyone recommended and the first Instr still returns 0.